# Resize UIToolBar icons in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I have big UIToolBar items. How can I resize them in code or in IB?

(this is looks like this:)

[image: UIToolBar Big Icons]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you use the @2x images directly as toolbar button images. In interface builder, remove the @2x suffix from the buttons. This is easier if you use the new asset catalog of Xcode 5.

Comment: i don't have something other. this is the files i received from the Designer. what is the normal height/width for UIToolBar item?

Comment: @theShay You should have your designer make the icons in the resolution you require. That will solve this issue, and will help keep the bundle size down.